# spark HWC cannot write to an existing table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, save, hdp

In HDP 3.1.0, HWC hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar, I cannot append (or overwrite) to an existing table depending on the database.

I tested on one datase called DSN, it works and on another database called CLEAN_CRYPT it fails.
Both databases are crypted + kerberos

```
import com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSession._
import com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSession
val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()
hive.execute("show databases").show()
hive.setDatabase("clean_crypt")
val df=hive.execute("select * from test")
df.write.format(HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR).option("table","test").mode("append").save
```

The error message is "table already exists". I tried overwrite mode without success.
If I drop the table, it passes !!!

Any idea ?

Comment: As you mention two different outcomes for different tables, please show the queries for both. Also are the tables similar? (types, partition)

Comment: Hi Denis, Both tables has same structure in different "database".It's curious because a database is just a directory for hive.

Comment: Are the security permissions (especially update) the same? Both in ranger and on hdfs

Comment: the same test in beeline is working so it is not ranger. A statement: hive.executeQuery("insert into clean_crypt.test select * from dsn.test") is working too. It's only when using a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to a HWC bug which is reported by multiple users [here](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap/issues/266).

What I've found is that it only occurs if you try to use a `partitionBy` at writing, like:

```
df.write.partitionBy("part")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.format(com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR)
.option("table", "`default`.`testout`").save;
```

On an other note, if you remove the `partitionBy` piece, partitioning works as expected (as partition info is already stored in the Hive table), but if you use overwrite mode (and not, for example, append), HWC will drop and recreate your table and it won't reapply partitioning info.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Hortnoworks connector and append to a partitioned table, you should not use `partitionBy` as it does not seem to work properly with this connector. Instead, you could use the partition options and add Spark parameters for dynamic partitioning.

Example:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder
import com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("yarn")
  .setAppName("My application")
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(sparkConf)
  .getOrCreate()

val hive = HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()
val hiveDatabase = "clean_crypt")
hive.setDatabase(hiveDatabase)
val df = hive.execute("select * from test")

df
    .write
    .format(HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .option("partition", partitionColumn)
    .option("table", table)
    .save()
```

For the above, the `hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.4.0-315.jar` was used. If the table does not exist, the connector creates it and stores it (by default) in ORC format.